# Can't push to my heroku app

Tags: git, heroku

I am having problems when pushing to heroku app. I have an existing repo and created a heroku app through the console.

I did

```
heroku git:remote -a myapp
```

Then when I do

```
git push heroku master
```

I get:

```
fatal: bad tree object 06c7dcf7e58e681253c74c381bb08827575046d3
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git'
fatal: write error: Bad file descriptor
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix a bad git tree object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005756/how-to-fix-a-bad-git-tree-object)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution from heroku support. The repo can be resset by running:

```
heroku repo:reset
```