# Pushing to git gives me an error: missing necessary objects

Tags: git

When I push to git, I get the following error

`git push origin test`

```
Enumerating objects: 30, done.
Counting objects: 100% (23/23), done.
Delta compression using up to 10 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
Writing objects: 100% (12/12), 1.01 KiB | 1.01 MiB/s, done.
Total 12 (delta 9), reused 2 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (9/9), completed with 8 local objects.
remote: fatal: bad object refs/__gh__/pull/55783/rebase
To git.corp.test.com:Test/t.git
 ! [remote rejected]         test -> test (missing necessary objects)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git.corp.test.com:Test/t.git'
```

Can someone please help?

When I do git fsck --full, I get

```
@Brian61354270

Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (2233797/2233797), done.
error: refs/remotes/origin/HEAD: invalid sha1 pointer 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Checking connectivity: 2233798, done.
dangling commit 0f22008e44c7ab5f73699a9b551241dcd00d73d4
dangling commit 642a800151da6bc94d343b57024a426063510051
dangling commit 2536007f58b1bf0ac6ac380dca963b83b2380c4d
dangling commit 0041802fada7edd6a7ce9de72486751742e441d9
dangling commit cd5680d2187338d495eb86bcccbde156c9d10ad6
dangling commit ca618036e28c9c56ef3abd70a9f259383f905311
```

Comment: What does `git fsck --full` report?

Comment: Please include new information in the question with an [edit]. Comments aren't permanent

Comment: @Brian61354270 updated the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve Git reporting invalid sha1 pointer 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59347462/how-to-resolve-git-reporting-invalid-sha1-pointer-000000000000000000000000000000)

Comment: @Brian61354270 This might be just slightly off topic, but what do you mean by, "comments aren't permanent"? The only way they are lost is if they are deleted by someone, but that's no different from how questions work....